# Block Let's Encrypt validation protocol for clients on guest network

Tags: https

I've setup a guest network behind the same public IP as a home web server running [Seafile](https://www.seafile.com/en/home/), communication between it and the clients is secured by the HTTPS protocol using a certificate signed by a local root CA.

How can I stop clients on the guest network from issuing certificates for the web server's domain using a service like Let's Encrypt on my behalf? I don't know how the validation process works for those sort of services, but I'd imagine that you need to be a able to send a receive packets from that address in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you read up on how letsencrypt validation works?

Comment: Disable their ability to manage your and and/or web servers.

Comment: @user430214 that'd be implementation specific. I'd like to know if there's a standard way of doing it.

Comment: Manage your DNS***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to block letsencrypt (or any CA) issuing for you domain, then publish a CAA record within your domain.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization

So if you want to block all CAs you could add a record like

```
example.com.    IN      CAA     0 issue ";"
```